# No comprendo porque aparece un error de tipo: TypeError('los índices de la lista deben ser enteros o rebanadas, no str',)

Tags: python, bucle-for, diccionarios

El problema trata de obtener una aproximacion de las notas de estudiantes. Las notas de los estudiantes y los nombres están en una lista de diccionarios. Después de obtener la aproximación de las notas debo ingresarlo en un diccionario con el mismo orden que el de entrada, con "nombres" y "nota".
No sé si hay algo mal a parte del error de los indices, muchas gracias.

```
def aproximar_notas(nombre:str, nota:float)->float:
    
    if nota >= 4.5:
        nota = 5.0
    elif nota >= 3.5 and nota < 4.5:
        nota = 4.0
    elif nota >= 2.5 and nota < 3.5:
        nota = 3.0
    else: 
        nota = 1.5
  
def calcular_definitivas(estudiantes:list)->list:

    notas_aproximadas = []
    for nota in estudiantes:
        nota = estudiantes['nota']
        nombre = estudiantes['nombre']
        
        partes_nota = nota.split(" ")
        partes_nombre = nombre.split(" ")
        
        nombre = str(partes_nombre[0])
        nota = float(partes_nota[0])
        notas_aproximadas = aproximar_notas(nombre, nota)
        dic_notas = {"nota": notas_aproximadas}
        notas_aproximadas.append(dic_notas)
    return(notas_aproximadas)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El parámetro `estudiantes` que recibe la función `calcular_definitivas` es una lista. Por lo tanto no puedes escribir más adelante `estudiantes["nota"]` que sería una operación válida para un diccionario, pero no para una lista (eso es lo que te está diciendo el error, que el índice de una lista no puede ser una cadena).

Sospecho que querías acceder a la nota de un alumno concreto (cada elemento de la lista es un diccionario con los datos de un alumno).

El error sería más fácilmente evitable si hubieras elegido un mejor nombre para la variable del bucle `for` la que has llamado `nota`, pero sospecho que mejor se hubiera llamado `estudiante`. Quedaría entonces así:

```
def calcular_definitivas(estudiantes:list)->list:

    notas_aproximadas = []
    for estudiante in estudiantes:
        nota = estudiante['nota']
        nombre = estudiante['nombre']
        # etc...
```

No me canso de repetir la importancia que tiene elegir buenos nombres para las variables. Si `estudiantes` es una lista de alumnos, cada uno de sus elementos será lógicamente un `estudiante` y no una `nota` (nombre que además te veías obligado a reasignar dentro del bucle con otro significado).

**Nota**. Hay otros aparentes errores de diseño. Por ejemplo ¿para qué recibe el parámetro `nombre` la función `aproximar_notas()` si no lo está usando para nada? ¿Para qué calculas el `nombre` (con el split y todo eso) si al final tampoco lo usas? ¿No debería ir ese `nombre` en el diccionario `dic_notas`?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha quedado claro, la verdad que no he pensado bien como los nombraba, gracias.

Comment: Si ha resuelto tu duda podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada :)